# Сравнение переменной по начальному слову её содержимого

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Не знаю, можно ли так сделать: Необходимо, чтобы в условии шла проверка только начального слова. Например, `$var = 'magazine%';` Вместо `%` может идти что угодно, как, например в поиске оператором `like` ставится `%` в начале и в конце, что означает, перед запроса и после запроса может идти что угодно. Так и мне нужно если значение переменной начинается с определённого слова, то выполнять действие.
Нужно для подсветки раздела на стороне сервера (добавлять класс).

Answer (score 2):

Элементарно, Ватсон:

```
<?
$var = 'magazine shop';
if(preg_match('!^magazine.*!', $var)){
 // Выполняем подсветку или что там.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все решается проще некуда. В PHP есть специальная функция для этого: **[strpos](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)**

> strpos — Возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки

Ваш пример:

```
$var = 'magazine%';
// Если в начале исходной строки встретилось 'magazine'
if (strpos($var, 'magazine') === 0) {
    // Добавить класс
}
```

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо обоим! А я ломаю голову второй день, как шаблоны светить...